# "requested datatype primary not available" when adding Remi repositories

Tags: centos, yum

In our daily autotests we install PHP 7.3 from Remi's repository using Ansible. Usually it works fine, but sometimes (few times a month) it fails with the error like below:

```
fatal: [vm1.int.zone]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "allow_downgrade": false, 
        "conf_file": null, 
        "disable_gpg_check": false, 
        "disable_plugin": [], 
        "disablerepo": null, 
        "enable_plugin": [], 
        "enablerepo": "epel,remi,remi-php73", 
        "exclude": null, 
        "install_repoquery": true, 
        "installroot": "/", 
        "list": null, 
        "name": [
            "php", 
            "php-mcrypt", 
            "php-mbstring", 
            "php-xml", 
            "php-xsl", 
            "php-xmlrpc", 
            "php-pdo", 
            "php-cli", 
            "php-pgsql", 
            "php-pspell", 
            "php-pecl-ssh2", 
            "php-pecl-zip", 
            "php-smbclient", 
            "php-intl", 
            "php-mysql", 
            "php-curl", 
            "php-xdebug", 
            "php-process"
        ], 
        "security": false, 
        "skip_broken": false, 
        "state": "installed", 
        "update_cache": false, 
        "update_only": false, 
        "validate_certs": true
    }
}, 
"msg": "Failure talking to yum: requested datatype primary not available"
```

There are 3 Remi repos:

```
# ll -d /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/remi*
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct 22 22:12 /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/remi
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct 22 22:12 /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/remi-php73
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct 22 22:12 /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/remi-safe
```

and any of these cause the problem if running certain yum commands, for example:

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror2.int.zone
 * epel: mirror2.int.zone
 * extras: mirror2.int.zone
 * remi-safe: mirror.serverion.com
 * updates: mirror2.int.zone
Error: requested datatype primary not available
```

If disable Remi's repos, everything goes fine. The problem is in broken cache for Remi's repository, for example:

```
# ll /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/remi-php73/
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 22 22:12 cachecookie
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 22 22:12 gen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2996 Oct 22 22:12 mirrorlist.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 22 22:12 packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2259 Oct 22 22:12 repomd.xml

# ll /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/remi-php73/gen/
total 0
```

Usually, this directory looks like this:

```
# ll /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/remi-php73/
total 232
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 211219 Oct 22 14:03 7042a64df80e22496ef9a31990242357a84898e0f0272915cf7cce20b705d863-primary.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Oct 23 04:24 cachecookie
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Oct 23 04:24 gen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2996 Oct 23 04:24 mirrorlist.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Oct 23 04:25 packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3095 Oct 22 14:03 repomd.xml

# ll /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/remi-php73/gen/
total 996
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1015808 Oct 22 14:03 primary_db.sqlite
```

So the files **{long_id}-primary.sqlite.bz2** and **gen/primary_db.sqlite** are missing for some reason sometimes.

The question is what can be a reason of this?

Comment: Update: yum makecache fixes the issue, I am wondering what originally causes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was in some broken mirror, see the topic:

https://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?pid=10903#p10903